# custom view declared in xml

Tags: android, android-xml

When declaring custom view in xml, what is the difference between declaring a View of a custom class, or declaring a completely custom view:

```
<LinearLayout>
<view class="packageName.MyView" android:id="@+id/myView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<LinearLayout>
<packageName.myView android:id="@+id/myView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

?

I've created a subclass of EditText, and when instatiating it as `View class=".."` my Activity crashes with ClassCastException when trying to access MyView:

```
(MyView) myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

When declared as second option, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but let me give it a go. A couple of things could be happening. The parser might not understand the `class` attribute correctly (e.g. it thinks it is part of a stylesheet). I am not sure how the parser handles the class attribute, since I have never seen or used it (in fact, I've never seen the `<View>` tag used either). A better explanation, though, might be this: the parser is trying to down-cast your `View` into `packageName.myView` class and fails (down-casting is always risky; up-casting is always safe).

Regardless of what is happening, I would always use the second option you listed, `<packageName.myView android:id...>`, instead of using the `<View>` tag. Reason being, it's redundant to use the `<View>` tag. Everything in this xml file must be a view (LinearLayout, Button, TextView, etc. are all descendants of the View class).

Hope that helps. If you're really, really curious, you could always download the source code for the parser...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up always using the second opinion, although Android docs says it doesn't matter which one you use.